# Displaying a vertical dashed line centrally in a div

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

working on React with StyledComponents, each `<div>` in the below represents a different Styled Component.

Trying to achieve something like this:

[image]

But I ideally want to add the "dashed line" styles in the `progress-indicator` so that it it sits vertically below the indicator and spans the full height of `wrapping-container`. I've tried using `::before` & `::after` but with no success.

```css
.wrapping-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.progress-indicator {
  height: 22px;
  width: 22px;
  margin-right: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background: rgb(39, 40, 42);
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
}


.input {  
  border: 1px solid #ced4da;
  border-radius: 2px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  padding: 0.375rem 1.75rem 0.375rem 0.75rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapping-container">
  <div class="progress-indicator">2</div>
  <div class="input">Input</div>
</div>  


<div class="wrapping-container">
  <div class="progress-indicator">3</div>
  <div class="input">Input</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Check if this Bootstrap snippet helps you in any way https://bbbootstrap.com/snippets/multi-step-form-vertical-progressbar-and-floating-label-41789662

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I would do it is the following:

```css
.wrapping-container {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
}
.progress-indicator {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    color: #fff;
}
.progress-indicator::after {
    content: "";
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background: #000;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    border-radius: 50%;
    z-index: -1;
}
.progress-indicator::before {
    content: "";
    height: 40px;
    border: 1px dashed #000;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: -50px;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    z-index: -1;
}
.input {
    margin-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapping-container">
    <div class="progress-indicator">2</div>
    <div class="input">Input</div>
</div>  
<div class="wrapping-container">
    <div class="progress-indicator">3</div>
    <div class="input">Input</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this Jelle - for some reason my progress indicators don't appear as circles & their text is white. Dashes present in the DOM but also transparent. Would the use of #000 have a possible impact on this?

Comment: Maybe smart to look at the problem via the inspecter tool. See what kind of css, like making the element black, does to the code. If it works, you can add it to the code.

Comment: removing z-index-1 seemed to do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

A simple (if crude) way to achieve this:

```css
.dasher {
    border: 1px dashed #ced4da;
    max-width: 0px;
    min-height: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: -20px;
}
```

### DEMO

```css
.wrapping-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.progress-indicator {
  height: 22px;
  width: 22px;
  margin-right: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background: rgb(39, 40, 42);
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
}


.input {  
  border: 1px solid #ced4da;
  border-radius: 2px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  padding: 0.375rem 1.75rem 0.375rem 0.75rem;
}

.dasher {
    border: 1px dashed #ced4da;
    max-width: 0px;
    min-height: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: -20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapping-container">
  <div class="progress-indicator">2</div>
  <div class="input">Input</div>
</div>

<div class="dasher"></div>

<div class="wrapping-container">
  <div class="progress-indicator">3</div>
  <div class="input">Input</div>
</div>
```

Should give you this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I added a container and a single dashed block that will go directly through all the height `wrapping-container`:

```css
.container{
  position:relative;
}
.border-dash{
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 11px;
  border-left: 1px dashed black;
  height:calc(100% - 25px);
  width: 1px;
  display: block;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

### DEMO

```css
.wrapping-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.progress-indicator {
  height: 22px;
  width: 22px;
  margin-right: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background: rgb(39, 40, 42);
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
}


.input {  
  border: 1px solid #ced4da;
  border-radius: 2px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  padding: 0.375rem 1.75rem 0.375rem 0.75rem;
}
.container{
  position:relative;
}
.border-dash{
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 11px;
  border-left: 1px dashed black;
  height:calc(100% - 25px);
  width: 1px;
  display: block;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <span class="border-dash"></span>
  
  <div class="wrapping-container">
    <div class="progress-indicator">2</div>
    <div class="input">Input</div>
  </div>  

  <div class="wrapping-container">
    <div class="progress-indicator">3</div>
    <div class="input">Input</div>
  </div>

  <div class="wrapping-container">
    <div class="progress-indicator">4</div>
    <div class="input">Input</div>
  </div>
</div>
```